# Unable to install PyQt5 on MacOS

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, pyqt5

I have tried a million different ways to install PyQt5, but I keep getting the same error message. I attempted to install it in a Python virtual environment, but still no success. I tried downloading Qt to see if there were any dependencies that were missing, but it did not resolve the issue. I have tried updating pip, using Homebrew, downloading the source code, and many other methods, but I have still been unable to install it. I'm working on MacOS.

This is an example of what I have tried:

```bash
(env) firstLast@name-MacBook-Pro project % pip install pyqt5   
   
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/name/Documents/final_project/tfod/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/name/Documents/final_project/tfod/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/name/Documents/final_project/tfod/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/ky/630000/T/pip-build-env-129w2sdq/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/ky/630000/T/pip-build-env-129w2sdq/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/private/var/folders/ky/630000/T/pip-build-env-129w2sdq/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 602, in setup
          self.update(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/ky/630000/T/pip-install-blf1r8si/pyqt5_7df68330104f4a9dbfac80220bfcd894/project.py", line 165, in update
          raise UserException(
      sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 5):

### Generic macOS Solution:

On macOS, there is a known issue when trying to install PyQt5 that requires having Qt5 installed on the system and its `qmake` tool added to the system's PATH, as indicated in the [installation section](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/) of its PyPI page.

To install Qt5, you can run the following command in terminal:

```
brew install qt5
```

After installation, you'll need to locate the `qmake` tool path, which is usually found here: `/usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake`. To add this path to the system's PATH, you'll need to open the `.bash_profile` file in terminal by typing:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then, add the following line to the end of the file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:$PATH"
```

This will add the directory where `qmake` is installed to the system's PATH. Save and close the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, and then Enter. To apply the changes to the current session, run the following command:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

You can verify that `qmake` is now on the PATH by running the following command:

```
which qmake
```

This should resolve the issue and allow you to install PyQt5.

---

#### M1 Chip Specific Solution:

The M1 chip was introduced in November 2020 and is based on the [ARMv8.5 architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family), which is different from the [x86_64 architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) used in Intel-based Mac computers. As a result, applications such as PyQt had to be compiled to include ARM-compatible binaries to run on the M1 chip. To address this issue, the Qt team developed [universal binaries](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-on-apple-silicon) that are compatible with both Intel and [Apple Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) hardware.

However, these universal binaries are only available from version 6.2 and onwards. This can be confirmed by running the commands below:

```
aviolaris@arch:~$ curl -s https://pypi.org/pypi/PyQt5/json | jq -r '.releases | to_entries[] | .value[] | select(.filename | contains("universal")) | .url | split("/") | .[-1]'

aviolaris@arch:~$ curl -s https://pypi.org/pypi/PyQt6/json | jq -r '.releases | to_entries[] | .value[] | select(.filename | contains("universal")) | .url | split("/") | .[-1]'
PyQt6-6.2.0-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.2.1-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.2.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.2.3-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.3.0-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.3.1-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.4.0-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.4.1-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.4.2-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.5.0-1-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
PyQt6-6.5.0-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
```

With that being said, if you explicitly prefer not to use PyQt6, which is compatible with your system's architecture, out of the box, you can attempt to install PyQt5 by utilizing [Rosetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)), a built-in emulator that enables you to run x86_64 software on ARM-based Mac computers.

To use Rosetta:

- Go to <kbd>Applications</kbd>, select <kbd>Utilities</kbd> and find your **Terminal** app.
- Right-click the **Terminal** app and select <kbd>Duplicate</kbd>.
- Rename the duplicate app to something like "**Terminal_x86_64**".
- Right-click the **Terminal_x86_64** app, select <kbd>Get Info</kbd> and enable <kbd>Open using Rosetta</kbd> option.
- Open the **Terminal_x86_64** app and type `arch` to verify that it says "x86_64" now.

After completing these steps, you will be able to install PyQt5 in the **Terminal_x86_64** app by typing the relevant pip command.

Comment: When i run the command which qmake, I get the location /opt/homebrew/bin/qmake. How can I make it so that its /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake instead?

Comment: The location of `qmake` appears to be valid and has been added to the system's PATH, so there is no need to change it. Does your MacBook have the M1 chip by any chance?

Comment: It does have an M1 chip

Comment: That's likely the reason. Check the updated answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: `curl ...` command returns nothing. I have m2

Comment: @Dr.jacky the two curl commands were used solely to demonstrate how to determine which versions of PyQt include universal binaries. The first curl command, which you are likely referring to, checks for PyQt5 and returns no results since it lacks universal binaries. The second curl command checks for PyQt6 and presents the versions that do have universal binaries. However, it is important to note that while these commands contribute to a better understanding of the subject matter, they are not essential for issue resolution.

Comment: I did select "Open using Rosetta" for iTerm. However, typing`arch` returns "i386", not"x86_64". (M2 chip)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to move to pyqt6,

```
pip install pyqt6
```

It works for me without any problem on Python 3.9.17, MacOS 13.3, M2 Pro

Answer (score -1):

MacOS M1-2 Chip: Iterm application:

***First*** : open application => right click **Iterm** => get Info
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeEcC.png)

***Sencond*** : click open using rosetta
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTxYD.png)

***Third*** : open Iterm:

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

this worked with me

Comment: This appears to be a "thank you" to the existing answer, not a new answer. Please don't repeat answers.